# Spring AMQP with RabbitMQ receiving same message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have small rabbitmq spring boot application:

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
{
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    return factory;
}
```

Simple queue definition:

```
@Bean
public Queue queue()
{
    return new Queue("queue");
}
```

And a simple listener which logs the message:

```
@RabbitHandler
public void process(@Payload Message message)....
```

I am seeing that the same message is being sent multiple times before the 
removed from queue.

How can i change this config to ensure the message is sent exactly once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your listener throws an exception the message will be requeued and sent.

It cannot be sent multiple times otherwise - impossible.

Turn on DEBUG logging to watch the message flow.

Comment: here are the logs:http://pastebin.com/dWJFk46X. I enabled DEBUG level and I added a cache on the payload value, and I am seeing same value being sent to service.

Comment: In all cases `redelivered=false` so these are all discrete messages; they are not the same; perhaps the problem is on the sending side?

Comment: You were right, I had a loop that was submitting the same message repeatedly. Took some time to figure out the loop.